# R Shiny - dropdownMenu code in server - styling goes bonkers

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

For the dropdownMenu in the header, I want to change the icon reactively, so I have to place the code into server.  However the styling goes bonkers, is there a way to keep the original styling?  I've tried manually copying styles and setting everything important but it still doesn't work.

In this example, there are two dropdownMenu blocks, one in the ui (looks good) and one in the server (looks bad).  I want to make the bad one look the same as the good one.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      uiOutput("my_dropdown"), 
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "tasks",
        badgeStatus = "danger",
        icon = "Looks good"
      ) 
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$my_dropdown <- renderUI({
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "tasks",
        badgeStatus = "danger",
        icon = "Looks bad"
      )
    })
  }
)
```

This is what it looks like
[image: looks bad]

This is what it should look like
[image: looks good]

Comment: Hi Vlad, you should use `dropdownMenuOutput` and `renderMenu` instead of `uiOutput` and `renderUI`.

Comment: Hi Bas, unfortunately I can't say thank you in the comments or how wonderful your suggestion is, otherwise I would say THANK YOU that's WONDERFUL!!